# De Sitter Universe and Black Holes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology, spacetime, metric-tensor, event-horizon

A De Sitter universe is one where all matter is ignored so $H$ is a constant

$$H = \sqrt{\frac\lambda c}.$$

In this type of universe can you calculate the event horizon of a black hole just by using Hubble's Law or is that no longer applicable given $H$ is no longer time dependant ?

$$c = H R_{s}$$

where $R_{s}$ is the schawrzchild radius, $c$ is the speed of light and $H$ is the Hubble constant.

> Show that in this model there is an event horizon with radius $c/H$. Assuming the Hawking formula also works for the radius of this form of horizon, calculate the temperature of the event horizon in de Sitter space. How do you interpret this kind of thermal radiation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no black hole. The horizon is cosmological.  The scale factor is inflating exponentially so, at sufficiently large distance, any  object is receeding  from you faster than the speed of light.  (You need to draw some  null geodesiscs to make this statement rigorous.)  You can compute the Hawking temperature by noting that the Euclidean signature version of de Sitter space is a 4-sphere, and so periodic in the time direction.